# Не знаю как сделать, чтоб дата изменялась при изменении новости

Tags: javascript, html, css

как должно быть:

[image: как должно быть]

Надо сделать так, чтобы при изменении какой-либо новости менялся день/месяц/год, когда это было изменено

Смотрел в интернете и не как не могу найти. Есть только об отчете таймера и т.п

Comment: А откуда у Вас в принципе берутся новости?

Comment: можно при создании новости в самой модели прописать поле дата и заполнять объект. То каждая новость помимо самой новости будет иметь и дату ее создания, которую и можно выводить рядом с заголовком

Comment: или если вы эти новости с сервера выводите, то там же то же дата загрузки наверняка есть. В любом случае это какое то динамическое поле на мой взгляд. Если у вас получается саму новость изменить, то значит поле дата можно заполнить от этой новости.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const currentDate = new Date().toDateString();
```

затем передаём эту переменную в нужное место

Comment: Какое это имеет отношение к изменению какой-либо новости?

Comment: а изменение новости не скриптом происходит?

Comment: в конце выполнения скрипта по изменению/добавлению новости добавить эту строку

Comment: В том-то и дело, что мы не знаем как это вообще происходит.

Comment: а сайт не ваш что-ли?

Comment: Вы меня спрашиваете? Вопрос так-то не я задавал.

Comment: К тому же Ваш код всегда будет показывать текущую дату.

Comment: вы сами сказали **мы** не знаемкак это вообще происходит.
и, нет этот код добавляется в конец функции получения/изменения новости, таким образом переменная будет получать значение (то есть текущую дату) только при публикации/изменении новости

Comment: Да, потому что этого в вопросе не описано. Мы не знаем абсолютно ничего о бекенде или что там вообще есть. Окей, каким образом тогда делается публикация новости и с чего Вы взяли что бекенд на JS? И на счет помещения этого в конец файла. О каком файле речь? Если это допустим MVC?

Comment: взял с того, что в метках указан js

Comment: Ок, каким образом Ваш подход будет актуален с Nest или Express и к примеру с React на фронте? Да и в принципе, в каком виде тогда нужно хранить новость, чтобы Ваш код работал?

Comment: Ладно, ваша взяла. Я не учел этих факторов при написании ответа. Предположил что если бы использовались `Next` или `Express` их бы так же указали в метках (я дал ответ исходя из того малого объема информации который мне предоставили)